# codicion dentro de una consulta para elegir una union personalizada

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, inner

saludos necesito de su ayuda
Tengo cinco trablas ditribuidas de la siguiente manera.

una tabla **users** esta dentro de la DB **Data_clientes**

```
users: | id_user | id_sub_user | status |
       | ------- | ----------- | ------ |
       | 22      | A           | 1      |
       | 13      | 1           | 1      |
       | 6       | 4           | 1      |
```

la segunda tabla **shop** esta en el interior de la  DB **Data_tiendas**

```
shop: | id_user_shop|   rubro   | activo |
      | ----------- | --------- | ------ |
      |  6          | ropa      | 1      |
      |  13         | zapatos   | 0      |
      |  22         | comida    | 1      |
      | ...         | ...       | 0      |
```

y las ultimas tres estan que contienen datos de identificacion y estado civil (**nacional , extrangero, Vicitante**) estan dentro de la DB **Data_identificacion**

```
nacional : | id_user | id_sub_user | nombre |
           | ------- | ----------- | ------ |
           |  21     | A           | Juan   |
           |  22     | A           | Pedro  |
           |  23     | A           | Jose   |
           | ...     | A           | xxxx   |

extranjero : | id_user | id_sub_user | nombre |
             | ------- | ----------- | ------ |
             |  11     | 1           | Pepe   |
             |  12     | 1           | Lucas  |
             |  13     | 1           | Mito   |
             | ...     | 1           | xxxx   |

Vicitante : | id_user | id_sub_user | nombre |
            | ------- | ----------- | ------ |
            |  6      | 4           | Lucho  |
            |  55     | 4           | Fercu  |
            |  56     | 4           | Jonas  |
            | ...     | 4           | xxxx   |
```

debo unirlas considerando una **id_sub_user** de la tabla **users** como consición.

teniendo en cuenta que estoy implementando un procedimiento almacenado realice este código pero me ha generado error.

```
SELECT 
    A.id_user,
    A.status,
    B.rubro,
    B.activo,
    C.nombre
FROM
    Data_clientes.users A
    JOIN Data_tiendas.shop B ON A.id_user = B.id_user_shop 
    IF A.id_sub_user = 'A' THEN 
        JOIN Data_identificacion.CEDULA C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
    ELSEIF A.id_sub_user = '1' THEN
        JOIN Data_identificacion.DNI C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
    ELSE
        JOIN Data_identificacion.PASAPORTE C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
    END IF
    /*
        CASE A.id_sub_user
        WHEN 'A' THEN 
            JOIN Data_identificacion.CEDULA C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
        WHEN '1' THEN 
            JOIN Data_identificacion.DNI C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
        ELSE 
            JOIN Data_identificacion.PASAPORTE C ON A.id_user = C.id_user
        END
    */

    WHERE 
        A.status = 1 
    LIMIT 10;
```

intenté con **CASE** pero como al parecer bota el mismo error lo documenté.

ayuda porfavor.

**re-re-editado 2023-04-19 21:42:10.z500** :

emite este error

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF A.id_sub_user = 'A' THEN 
                JOIN Data_identificacion.CEDULA C ON A.Id_user' at line 10
```

Comment: Que error??? que tiene que ver jquery??? que tiene que ver store_procedure??? ahi no se ve ningun problma con que este en otro servidor (lo que eso quiera decir)....

Comment: etiquetas corregidas, lleve un ejemplo de las data b en solo servidor e implemente un procedimiento almacenado y sigue saliendo erro

Comment: la tabla Data_identificacion son 3 tablas o es la misma tabla?

Comment: son 3, una por cada tipo de documento de identificación, esto se debe a que el número de documento es tambien su ID y por ende su llave foranea no duplicable almacenado en formato INT, y como hay cedulas y pasaportes que empiesan con ceros a la izquierda, esto aria conflicto en algun momento con la identificacion de otra persona al ingresarlo.

Comment: si es una base nueva, eso es un error!!! el id de la persona no tiene nada que ver con la documentacion.. si es una base vieja.. bueno... estas complicado...

Comment: tenes 3 tablas que se llaman igual????? como haces eso????

Comment: Te estás haciendo un lío innecesario... ¿Qué pasaría si necesitas agregar un tipo de documento diferente, como una cédula de extranjería o un permiso especial de permanecía? ¿Agregas una nueva tabla y modificas el query?. En su lugar podrías tener una sola tabla con los datos de identificación, un campo con ID auto incrementable, un campo con el tipo de documento, y otro con el número de documento. La validación al insertar en esta tabla sería que no se repita el tipo de documento y el número de documento... Sales mejor librado.

Comment: claro DjCrazy, concuerdo que ese es el modelo ideal.
gbianchi, no quiero ser grocero pero creo sin temor a equivocarme que nunca has trabajado en centros de identificacion de tu pais.

Comment: Te equivocas... pero eso no quiere decir que las tablas esten mal.. igual, vuelvo a preguntar, como tenes 3 tablas con el mismo nombre en la misma base de datos???? son 3 tablas? o es 1 tabla que ves particionada?

Comment: Que es `rubro` en `C`? Querías decir `nombre`? Por qué las tablas de la query y las que pones de ejempo no coinciden? Es porque intentaste simplificar un ejemplo? Qué versión de MySQL estas usando?

Comment: tenias razon si al copiar la linea de texto copie mal y en vez de dejar C.nombre le puse rubro.
por otro lado este es un ejemplo simplificado del problema ya que el codigo original es mas grande, con mas inner joins que un rosario para rezar.

Comment: Bueno.. tu ejemplo no ejemplifica el problema porque es una sola tabla.. si tenes 3 tablas, podrias generar un vista que las una, y tu join se simplificaria... pero, no estas mostrando algo logico con lo cual se pueda trabajar, tenemos que suponer mil escenarios...

Comment: ok, para el ejemplo tengo 3 DB albergadas en un mismo servidor, en dos de ellas solo tengo una rabla que consultar, y en la ultima tres, la verdad ya no me quedan ideas como explicar esta embroyo o sera que mi latino se confunde con el español,

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este tipo de inconveniente para el alguna alma desventurada es:

elaborar una tabla que contenga todos los numeros de identificación y un campo que sirva para identificar a que tipo de documento de identificación pertenese es número.

ejemplo :

```
cumulo   : | id_user | id_sub_user |
           | ------- | ----------- |
           |  21     | A           |
           |  22     | A           |
           |  23     | A           |
           |  11     | 1           |
           |  12     | 1           |
           |  13     | 1           |
           |  6      | 4           |
           |  55     | 4           |
           |  56     | 4           |
           | ...     | ...         |
```

luego la consutal es como esta:

```
                SELECT 
                    A.status ,
                    B.rubro,
                    B.activo,
                    CASE WHEN A.Id_type_doc = '1' THEN
                        G.nombre 
                    WHEN A.Id_type_doc = 'A' THEN
                        H.nombre 
                    ELSE
                        I.nombre 
                    END AS nombre
                    
                    
                FROM
                    Data_clientes.users A
                    JOIN Data_tiendas.shop B ON A.id_user = B.id_user_shop
                    JOIN Data_identificacion.cumulo C ON A.id_user = C.id_user AND A.id_sub_user = C.id_sub_user
                    
                    
                    LEFT JOIN Data_identificacion.nacional G    ON A.id_user = G.id_user AND A.id_sub_user = G.id_sub_user
                    LEFT JOIN DNI_RUC_PAS_CED_OTR.extranjero H  ON A.id_user = H.id_user AND A.id_sub_user = H.id_sub_user
                    LEFT JOIN DNI_RUC_PAS_CED_OTR.Vicitante I   ON A.id_user = I.id_user AND A.id_sub_user = I.id_sub_user
                    
                WHERE 
                    A.status = 1
                    ORDER BY nombre ASC;
```

esto seria todo, obviamente hay que cambiar un poco la forma como se registran los nuevos nacidos u otros usuarios, para que ingresen los datos en el cumulo paralelamente, pero es tema de implementacion.
en mi caso se planteo esta resolución y actualizar el diseño he implementarlo no fue la gran cosa.